# When a service is injected into a parent controller should I also inject into the child or just inherit the service

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to understand how to bring a service into a controller when the service is used in both a parent and child controller and the parent and child HTML. Should I bring the service into the parent and then get a copy of that service from the scope in the child like this:

```
class AppController {
    static $inject = [
        '$scope',
        'configService'
    ]
    constructor(
        public $scope: IAppControllerScope,
        public config: IConfigService
        ) { 
        $scope.app = this;
        $scope.config = config;
    }
    // this.config is used here
} 
class AdminHomeController { 
    public app: AppController;
    public config: ConfigService;
    static $inject = [
        '$scope'
    ];
    constructor(
        private $scope: IAdminHomeControllerScope
        ) {  
        this.app = $scope.app;
        this.config = $scope.config;
        $scope.home = this;
    }
    // this.config is used here
}
```

Or should I bring the service into both the parent and child controllers like this:

```
class AppController {
    static $inject = [
        '$scope',
        'configService'
    ]
    constructor(
        public $scope: IAppControllerScope,
        public config: IConfigService
        ) {
        $scope.app = this;
        $scope.config = config;
    }
    // this.config is used here
} 
class AdminHomeController {
    public app: AppController;
    static $inject = [
        '$scope',
        'configService'
    ];
    constructor(
        public $scope: IAdminHomeControllerScope,
        public config: IConfigService
        ) {
        this.app = $scope.app;
        $scope.home = this;
    }
    // this.config is used here
}
```

I would appreciate any advice and suggestions on which would be the best way to do this and if there are differences. One more question. Should the parameters on my constructors be declared as private or public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your choice really, however you prefer to do it, but the one argument for including it in each controller directly is that you have no dependencies on anything else.

The issue with having it included by the `AppController` and inherited, is that if for whatever reason one developer decided "we don't kneed this in here anymore", you would then have all other controllers that assume the service is there break. - @basarat tells me that TypeScript would in fact simply fail to compile, but this is obviously still more of a problem than there not being one. In this scenario, you'd either have to put it back, or go into every controller that gave a compilation error and inject it into them, so you'd end up back at the first solution anyway.

By including it directly into each and every controller, it makes no difference to the rest of the application if you remove it from one of them. It just keeps things a bit safer.

If you really want to just include it once and use it everywhere, you should be able to use the angular `run` method to inject it into the rootScope when the app runs. You could do something like the following.

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, myService) {
  $rootScope.myService = myService;
})
// For declaring that myService exists on all instances of $scope: 
module ng{
    export interface IScope{
         myService: MyService;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't break badly in typescript.

Comment: What doesn't? The code I posted or removing the service from the app controller?

Comment: If you update the base scope to remove the service, the remaining controllers will fail to compile. So the usage argument is not valid here.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't realise it did compile time checks. Still applies though that if a developer removed it from the app controller, it would break the application if other controllers depended on it, just at compile time instead of runtime

Comment: :) Thanks for correcting me. I have no experience with TypeScript, but think I may take a look. Quite like the idea of it knowing when angularJS code is wrong

Comment: I added a bit of TypeScript to your answer. Hope its okay with you.

Comment: No problem that's great :) Helps others looking for the answer in TypeScript :)

Comment: @basarat - Sorry if this is a dumb question but if it is included in each controller will that always be the same singleton instance of the service? Given your experience with AngularJS and Typescript what would be the way you suggest. Thanks

Comment: @Alan `if it is included in each controller will that always be the same singleton instance of the service?` yes

Comment: @Alan `Given your experience with AngularJS and Typescript what would be the way you suggest` This answer is what I use personally as well for app wide services.